# how can i launch edge in compatibility mode with robotframework?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I'm needing some help, I have to test an app that works in Internet Explorer, the problem is that Internet Explorer is no longer available in Windows 10, so it has been thought to use edge in compatibility mode. I have to automate a process on an application that works in ie so now I must be able to launch edge in compatibility mode. The application server was configured so that when the application is accessed automatically edge detects it as having to open it in compatibility mode, if I enter the url manually the app runs in compatibility mode, instead if I open it using robotframework+selenium with the open browser command I get a label that says: disable remote debugging to open the site in internet explorer mode. From what I saw [on the microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode?tabs=python#the-complete-sample), I must start the ie driver with an option that indicates where the edge executable is so that it works in compatibility mode, but I don't know how to do it in robot framework.
This is the way I am trying now:

```
    ${ie_options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].IeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
Call Method    ${ie_options}    add_argument    binary_location\=C:${/}Program Files (x86)${/}Microsoft${/}Edge${/}Application${/}msedge.exe
Create WebDriver    ie   ie_options=${ie_options}
```

But it throws me the following error:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a response in the general channel In RobotFramework Slack, I already managed to do it in the following way:
Open Browser  https://www.google.com/  ie    options=ignore_zoom_level=True; attach_to_edge_chrome=True; edge_executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"